# Iterating over an array with class properties as keys

Tags: php

I have two classes - one that is a User object, and the other that is a Drupal View that shows links (just another object, for purposes of this question). The content the Drupal View displays has properties like 'field_carries_trucks', 'field_carries_cars'. These are meant to be boolean properties (whether they are true or false is designated by checkbox), but the way it turns out in Drupal is they become array values.

So as an example, if I want to check the value of a property of a particular link(whether the 'carries cars' is checked for that particular piece of content) I do a var_dump on

```
$view->_field_data[nid][entity]->field_carries_cars[und][0][value]
```

So field_carries_cars in this example is an array. Doing a var dump on the above yields a 0 or 1.

As for the User class, the User class has boolean properties like ('sees_cars'). Basically, its a boolean for whether the User can see a certain link or not.

Now, my goal is to have an elegant way to filter whether the user can see a link. So here is what I have done:

```
$permissions = array(
 'field_carries_trucks' => 'user_sees_trucks',
 'field_carries_cars' => 'user_sees_cars',
 'field_carries_vans' => 'user_sees_vans',
);
```

Then my goal is to do a simple check of

```
foreach($permissions as $field => $user_perm) {
  if($view->result[]->_field_data[nid][entity]->$field[und][0][value] == $user->$user_perm) {
    echo 'Can view';
  }      
}
```

Basically, if the field properties of the link (i.e., is a cars link) and the properties of the user (i.e., can view cars links), then the link should be displayed.

Here's my problem. If I do:

```
foreach($permissions as $field => $user_perm) {  
  var_dump($view->result[]->_field_data[nid][entity]->$field)
}
```

just to troubleshoot, nothing comes up.

My goal here is to avoid having to hardcode all these permission checks. What am I doing wrong? Alternatively, what can I do to make this elegant?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the array index 0

```
foreach($permissions as $field => $user_perm) {  
  var_dump($view->result[**0**]->_field_data[nid][entity]->$field)
}
```

Ok?

Comment: No...you're missing the point. THat's not the problem. I left that out intentionally....

Comment: That's the thing - you can't leave that out. `[]` is an assignment operator, but you're trying to read